# php - Função autocompletar

Tags: php, javascript

Estou usando a função autocompletar em um projeto, quando uso local tudo ocorre bem, mas quando hospedo apenas o primeiro campo funciona:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cliee").autocomplete("../acoes/pesquisa/insertProjeto.php", {
        selectFirst: false,
        scrollHeight: 220
    });

}); 

function habCampo(){

    var proj = document.getElementById('cliee').value;

        $("#projj").autocomplete('../acoes/pesquisa/insertTipoProjeto.php?i='+proj, {
            selectFirst: false,
            scrollHeight: 220
        });


}
```

Quando primeiro campo é preenchido, ele envia para função `habCampo` o id de cliente, que tento passar para outra pagina, para fazer um select, onde o usuário vai digitar e ira retornar só os projetos que estão vinculados ao cliente.

Como disse, local funciona perfeito, mas em produção não funciona. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar a URL absoluta ao invés de relativa? E quando a função `habCampo` é chamada?

Comment: possuo 2 campos, o primeiro é parâmetro para o segundo, campo CLIENTE e campo PROJETO, quando coloco o foco no segundo campo, ele acessa o haCampo trazendo valor do primeiro campo CLIENTE, para que possa fazer um select com essas informações e trazer os dados no input para o usuário escolher.